# Retrieving relationships of relationships using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a database with the following tables and relationships:
invoice ,order & product
each factor has several orders,and every orders point to a product.

---

Invoice Model:

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

---

Order Model:

```
class order extends Model
{
    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);
    }
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }   
}
```

---

Product Model:

```
class product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

---

the name of each order is foreign key to the product id,

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('name')->references('id')->on('products')->default(0);
```

in my template i can showing the invoice with orders like this:

```
{{$invoice->title}}
{{$invoice->client_address}}

@foreach($invoice->orders as $order)
    {{$order->name}}
    ${{$order->price}}
    {{$order->qty}}
    ${{$order->qty * $order->price}}
@endforeach
```

with this function:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::with('orders')->findOrFail($id);
    return view('admin.invoice.show.main', compact('invoice'));
}
```

how can show the name of product in orders recorde like this:

```
{{$order->product->name}}
```

im using before for single loop(e.g., product & category)
but in this example we have 3 relation and using a compact method before.

---

My product table is:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('desc');
    $table->string('price');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->string('count');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->default(0);
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$invoice = Invoice::with('orders.product')->findOrFail($id);
```

You can access using something like that

```
@foreach($invoice->orders as $order)
..
 {{ $order->product->name }}
..
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your relations is wrong...Each product can be within a few orders..so:

Product Model:

```
class product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Order Model:

```
class order extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product');
    }   
}
```

right?

Then access with:

```
$invoices = Invoice::with('orders.product')->get();
```

Comment: i have this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.order_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`order_id` in (150, 151))

Comment: what is your product table's columns? @MohammadrezaAhmadpour

Comment: Shouldn't this be a ManyToMany relationship? One Product can be in Many orders and an Order can contain Many Items? Anyway if you change your relations like this you need to change your table structure and add a order_id foreign key field to your products table.

Comment: i add the product table's columns in main post.

Comment: @MohammadrezaAhmadpour and where you save (order_product) details and connections?

Comment: You can make middle table (order_product) that has columns product_id and order_id @MohammadrezaAhmadpour